# Questions involving $f(x)=x^2+\int_{-1}^1(x+y)f(y)\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on $\mathbb R$ and satisfying $f(x)=x^2+\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1(x+y)f(y)\,dy$ where $x$ and $y$ are independent variables.
>
> - A) If $f(x)\gt k$ for every real $x$, find the largest integral value of $k$.
> - B) If $h(t)=f(-t)-f(t)$ for every $t\in\mathbb R$ then find the value of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac\pi2}h(t)\sin tdt$.
> - C) If the range of function $g(x)=3f(x)+b+4$ for every real $x$ is $[0,\infty)$, find the value of $b$.

A) If put $x=-y$, I get $f(-y)=y^2\implies f(y)=y^2\implies f(x)=x^2\implies f(x)\ge0$. But the answer given is $-3$

B) $h(t)=0$. But the answer given is $4$.

Looks like my approach is entirely wrong.

I had also tried taking derivative of $f(x)$ but couldn't conclude.

$$f'(x)=2x+\int_{-1}^1f(y)\,dy$$

Comment: You cannot set $x=-y$ in (A) because $y$ is an integration variable.

Comment: @user619894 Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying and using integral properties, we have that $f$ can be rewritten as
$$f(x) = x^2 + x\int_{-1}^1 f(y) dy + \int_{-1}^1 y f(y) dy$$
Thus $$f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$$
with $\displaystyle b = \int_{-1}^1 yf(y) dy$ and $\displaystyle a = \int_{-1}^1 f(y)dy$.

Integrating both sides from $-1$ to $1$ gives us

$$a = \frac{2}{3} + 2b$$

We got a relation between $a$ and $b$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thankyou but I am not sure how to exploit the relation between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @aarbee We can find another relation for $a$ and $b$ to solve the problem. Try to integrate $xf(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx$ from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Hi. I had got it 2 weeks ago. I think I lost it again. I am getting $a=2, b=2/3, f(x)=x^2+2x+2/3=(x+1)^2-1/3\ge-1/3\implies k=-1$ but the answer given is $-3$. Can you point out my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: @aarbee The value of $a$ and $b$ should be $-2$ and $-4/3$ respectively. The system is \begin{align*}
a &= \frac{2}{3} + 2b \\
b &= \frac{2a}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot...